# Setting up virtual host by editing apache httpd.conf (for Zend framework) opens XAMPP page, not Zend's

Tags: apache-2.2, php, xampp, zend-framework

Setting up a virtual host apache (for Zend framework application) opens XAMPP homepage, but I need Zend default project home page instead.

Am I doing something wrong?

I made a virtual host as follows :

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "A:\xampp\htdocs\zend_projects\leadscapture_intern"
   ServerName lc.intern
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include all brackets etc.
Also post the configuration as code `{}`-Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment edit your question. With that information we are not able to help you.

From the fragment provided by now you **should** disable (comment out) a couple of lines from the httpd.conf file. The following directives should not appear there:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/it
<Directory /path/to/it>
   Options...
   AllowOverride ...
   # directives until the closing bracket
</Directory>
```

You **must** enable the include of the `vhost.conf` file after that, or check for it to be. This is most likely the reason you don't see anything but the default page. It is handled with something like the following:  `Include path/to/vhost.conf` (path and filename may vary).

Last not least check your hosts file and add `127.0.0.1 lc.intern` for your browser to actually resolve your VH. Second reason it might not work.

**UPDATE**:
Additionally your VH configuration is incomplete. It should look more like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ic.intern
    DocumentRoot /tra/la/la
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /tra/la/la>
       Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /path/to/tralala_error
    CustomLog /path/to/tralala_access combined
</VirtualHost>
```

(quick and dirty)